# Setting Cookie for all browser tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, internet-explorer-11, mozilla

I want to set a cookie using javascript, which would be available for all the tabs in browser.

I have used `document.cookie = "tracker=ABC"`

Even I have tried to set the path also, but result remained same
`document.cookie = "tracker=ABC;path=/"`

However, this seems applicable only to the tab where it was set. This cookie is not visible to other tabs in the browser..

Also, I am not very clear with the path concept in cookies. Would be great if someone can tell me about it's use as a secondary answer

Regards,

SAP Learner

So my question is: How can I set a cookie which would be applicable for all the tabs in the browser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A cookie is not linked to a browser tab, but to a domain and its sub-domains.

If you couldn't create a "cross-tab" cookie, it's likely because the domains are different. It's an obvious security rule implemented by all browsers, that prevents domains from accessing other domains cookies.

If the domains are the same, then it works and you can verify it by yourself:

- open a tab, then open some website
- create some cookie with `document.cookie = "test"` in the console
- open another tab, then open the same website
- type `document.cookie` in the console and you'll be able to see the `test` cookie

Comment: Thanks for that tip.. I never realized this..
So if I set cookie as follows:
document.cookie = "tracker=ABC; domain=google.com; path=/"

then tracker cookie will be available when I access google.com in any tab.. Is this correct..

Also, can you tell me the use of path in cookies with an example..

Comment: Your assertion is correct, but you can only set a cookie with a domain if it matches (partially or totally) your application domain (only google can set google.com as a cookie domain)

Comment: The path is similar to the domain. When you set a domain it matches the domain and subdomains. When you set a path it matches the path and the subpaths